# Javascript Dynamic Conditionals

Tags: javascript

I want to create a dynamic amount of fields determined by the value selected in a dropDownList. As this will be executed client side it must be done through Javascript. I know I could achieve this effect by creating ALL of the fields before hand and then simply using css to show/hide each one, but this is a lot of repetitive code.

Through trial and error I've got it to kind of work, but it either deletes my values when changing my dropdownlist or adds too many boxes if I don't have it delete the previously created boxes before creating new ones.

Is there a simple way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, without losing entered values on change of the dropdownlist? My attempt at making something is below.

```
function doAThing() {
    var attemptsValue = parseInt(document.forms['ProgramApplicationForm'].elements['VerificationPrimaryHomePhoneAttemptsDropDownList'].value);

    if (attemptsValue == null) {
        document.getElementById('VerificationPrimaryHomePhoneAttemptDate').innerHTML = null;
    } else if (document.getElementById('VerificationPrimaryHomePhoneAttemptDate').innerHTML == null) {
        for (counter = 1; counter < attemptsValue + 1; counter++) {
            document.getElementById('VerificationPrimaryHomePhoneAttemptDate').innerHTML += 
            '<label for="VerificationPrimaryHomePhoneAttemptDate' + counter + '">Attempt ' + counter + ' Date:</label><input type="text" name="VerificationPrimaryHomePhoneAttemptDate' +  counter + '" value="" id="p-dod-date-picker" maxlength="10" class="size-ten" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" title="yyyy-mm-dd" pattern="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"/>'; 
        }            
    } else {
        document.getElementById('VerificationPrimaryHomePhoneAttemptDate').innerHTML = null;

        for (counter = 1; counter < attemptsValue + 1; counter++) {
            document.getElementById('VerificationPrimaryHomePhoneAttemptDate').innerHTML += 
            '<label for="VerificationPrimaryHomePhoneAttemptDate' + counter + '">Attempt ' + counter + ' Date:</label><input type="text" name="VerificationPrimaryHomePhoneAttemptDate' +  counter + '" value="" id="p-dod-date-picker" maxlength="10" class="size-ten" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" title="yyyy-mm-dd" pattern="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"/>';             
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`element.removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild) and [`element.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild) instead of meddling with `innerHTML`. This will enable you to remove specific nodes in the DOM:

```
<form name="ProgramApplicationForm">
<select id="VerificationPrimaryHomePhoneAttemptsDropDownList" name="VerificationPrimaryHomePhoneAttemptsDropDownList">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
    <div id="VerificationPrimaryHomePhoneAttemptDate"></div>
</form>
```

```js
function createLabelElement(i){
    /* Create the label */
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Attempt "+i+" Date:")); // add text

    /* create the input and set all attributes */
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.value = "";
    input.id="p-dod-date-picker"; // ids should be unique!
    input.maxlength = 10;
    input.className = "size-ten";
    input.placeholder = "yyyy-mm-dd";
    input.title = "yyyy-mm-dd";
    input.pattern = "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}";

     /* a label doesn't need "for", 
       you can actually put your input into the label element 
    */
    label.appendChild(input);

    return label; // return the created element
}

document.getElementById('VerificationPrimaryHomePhoneAttemptsDropDownList').addEventListener('change',function(){
   var numberOfElements = parseInt(this.value);
   var targetDiv = document.getElementById('VerificationPrimaryHomePhoneAttemptDate');   

   // As long we have to many elements remove them
   while(targetDiv.children.length > numberOfElements ){
        targetDiv.removeChild(targetDiv.lastChild);
   }
   // As long we have not enough elements add more
   while(targetDiv.children.length < numberOfElements){
        targetDiv.appendChild(createLabelElement(targetDiv.children.length + 1));
   }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Psv4/)

If you want you can still use `innerHTML` on the created labels, this will make the first function much smaller. Also note that `null` isn't a number, it's an object.

Comment: @EricG: No. If you place the `input` inside of the `label`, the `for` attribute isn't needed. Have a look at the [HTML specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1).

Answer (score 0):

Alright you're practising some bad practises here. You are accessing the innerHTML property both as the document in a loop. Also, you have the 'else if' and the 'else' exactly the same.

I would rewrite is as follow:

```
function doAThing() {
var d = document;
var attemptsValue = parseInt(d.forms['ProgramApplicationForm'].elements['VerificationPrimaryHomePhoneAttemptsDropDownList'].value);

var attemptDate = d.getElementById('VerificationPrimaryHomePhoneAttemptDate');
if (attemptsValue == null) {
        attemptDate.innerHTML = null;
    } else {

        var html = "";
        for (counter = 1; counter < attemptsValue + 1; counter++) {
            html += 
            '<label for="VerificationPrimaryHomePhoneAttemptDate' + counter + '">Attempt ' + counter + ' Date:</label><input type="text" name="VerificationPrimaryHomePhoneAttemptDate' +  counter + '" value="" id="p-dod-date-picker" maxlength="10" class="size-ten" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" title="yyyy-mm-dd" pattern="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"/>';
        }
        attemptDate.innerHTML = html;
}
}
```